# Spring Kafka - Prevent message loss in sequential processing and sending

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using **@RetryableTopic** to handle the **@KafkaListener** exceptions.
But i've the following scenario:

1. Listener of topic **A** poll a message, process it, and then sends a message to topic **B**
2. Listener of topic **B** poll a message, process it, and then sends a message to topic **C**
3. and so on

The problem is, the `KafkaTemplate#send` is **async**, so i can't throw an exception and let the @RetryableTopic handle this.

If there is a problem after the process, on the send of a message to the next topic, i dont want to lose the message, so i can maybe reprocess it until the send works.

The easiest workaround could be to make the send blocking and then throw an exception, but obviously blocking the producer thread impacts the performance.

Now i'm using `AckMode.RECORD`, maybe i've to move to `AckMode.MANUAL`, so i can do the ACK in the send success callback, and NACK in the failure one, but then i'll lose the @RetryableTopic

What could be the best way to handle this?

Comment: You can make the producer synchronous by calling get on the returned Future object, but other option may be to use transactions or Kafka Streams rather than consumer/producer

Comment: Ty for answering. Regarding the blocking send i know, i wrote it in my question, and ì don’t like it since it slows down the process. I can’t choose the other 2 options unfortunately

Comment: 1) Transactions are enabled by default in latest clients, though you still want to start/commit them 2) Kafka Streams is just a different client library within Spring Kafka, and it's designed to do exactly what you're trying to do (consume, process, and emit to other topics)

Comment: I’m not using Kafka but Oracle Cloud Streaming, which is compliant with Kafka APIs but does not support transactions. Maybe Kafka Streams could be the solution. But probably i have to rethink the retry logic right? Also for streams do you suggest the apache lib or the spring cloud one? Ty